# Simple explanation of Akka Actors

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Is the following statement correct, otherwise how can it be improved?

> When an Akka actor is sent a message, a job is submitted to the executor. 
>   When there is a free thread, it calls the job which obtains a lock on
>   the actor (assuming it can, otherwise another job is taken).  The
>   `receive` method of the actor is then called and once it completes,
>   the job is discarded and the thread returned to the pool.  The cycle is then repeated.
>   All the complicated stuff related to concurrent threads is
>   handled by Akka, freeing the programmer to concentrate on
>   solving business problems.

Comment: This is a description of a particular implementation is Actors, Akka I assume. You should modify it, and the title of your post to say so. If that was not your intention, then you are being much too focused on implementation details that are not present in all Actor systems.

Comment: Assuming Akka: I don't believe any locking of the actors themselves is involved. Each actor instance has it's own "mailbox" (a request queue—the term "job" is not used) and the queued messages are handed to the actor one at a time. Any given actor instance is never processing more than one request at a time. There can in general be any number of actors of a given type and they all operate independently.

Comment: See - [Carl Hewitt explains the essence of the Actor Model of computation](http://letitcrash.com/post/20964174345/carl-hewitt-explains-the-essence-of-the-actor) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model

Comment: Yes, I mean Akka, and I've updated the question.

Comment: There are indeed no locks involved in Akka’s implementation of the Actor model.

Comment: If you have 20 actors and just 10 threads, some will be in a wait state.  Some may have no messages in their mailboxes.  Does each get a chance to run, and when they run, they check their mailbox themselves?  Is that why no locking is needed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More accurate would be:

> When a message is sent to an actor, it is placed in this actor's queue called *mailbox*. At the same time there can be hundreds or thousands of actors having pending messages in their mailboxes. Akka, using limited number of worker threads, selects a subset of such actors and calls their `receive` method with each and every message from mailbox in chronological order.
>
> More than one thread never handles the same actor. Also Akka may decide to interrupt processing of messages from a mailbox and select different actor to remain fair and avoid starvation. Because one thread is needed for each `receive` invocation, this method should never block, wait or sleep.